# Where the data goes after a pop operation in a stack based VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, bytecode

Let's suppose that I have the following bytecode of a VM:

```
push constant 10
push constant 20
call add
pop
```

The result of this operation is `30`. I do understand what is the `push`, `pop` and `call` operations, and that `push` pushes the constant to the stack, call jumps to another branch and `pop` removes what is on the top of the stack. But where the value of the pop operation goes (in this case)? That's a mistery for me.

Comment: Why do you think it has to go somewhere? `int` values don’t have an immortal soul…

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere. `pop` throws the value away. It's sort of like what happens in high level source code if you call a function and don't store the result in a variable.